# Elliptical Arc Length

Tags: math

Given a point `P` on a 'canonical' ellipse defined by axes `a, b`, and an arc length `s`, how can I find a point `Q`, also on the ellipse, that is `s` clockwise along the elliptical curve from `P` — such that if I were to start at `P` and 'walk along' the elliptical curve for a distance of `s`, I would reach `Q` — programatically and without breaking the computational bank?

I have heard that this can be computed through some sort of elliptical integration, but I need to do this a bunch, and quickly. What I'm looking for is **an easy to use, computationally inexpensive, and fairly accurate approximation method.** Or at least a method that is one or two of those things. I will be implementing this in python.

**Edit:** alternatively, I might be forced to create a lookup table of position values around ellipses (I might only need in the 10s of dissimilar ellipses). How should I do this, and what method can I use to fill it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to integrate the ellipse equation. It's not difficult, actually.

Take a look at the equations here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180528154314/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51945.html)

Since you're using python, the Runge-Kutta for integration is implemented in Python here (I don't know the license, though):

http://doswa.com/blog/2009/04/21/improved-rk4-implementation/

Just on step 3 and 4 of mathforum solution you already have a value for ds (the arc lenght) and you want dx.

After finding dx, use step 6 to find y.

Comment: Agreed; true mathematical integration is as computationally simple and accurate as you're ever going to get.  I think what the asker is trying to avoid is "integration" in the sense of [Euler Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) or [Verlet Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration), which involves *literally* adding tiny `ds`'s to a point until you total up to your desired `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scipy.special.ellipeinc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipeinc.html) to calculate the arclengths. (More details are given by Roger Stafford [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/142587).)

If that isn't fast enough, you could wrap the arclength calculation in a function and use a [memoize decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) to cache the result of previous (arclength) function calls.

Or, as you've mentioned, you could pre-calculate the values you need, and store them in a dict.

Answer (score -2):

In order to solve the problems you need a conjeture:there is a circle in unit elipse
a=1, that it has the same perimeter han the elipse. That perim is 2πrp.your. perimeter is then P=2πrp x a

Comment: What are `p`, `r`, and `a`?  The original question is about finding the arc length along part of the ellipse.  You seem to be saying that to find the perimeter of the entire ellipse, you need to find the circumference of a circle that has the same perimeter.  Which is the same as saying "to find the perimeter, first find the perimeter".